# Local cache of Postgresql table/view

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, caching, memory

I'm developing a small NodeJS application, which uses data from a remote PostgreSQL database.
Everything works, but when scaling the lookup and round-trip time to/from the PostgreSQL are a hurdle.

I would like to implement a local cache of my table/view from PostgreSQL.

I've thought of using an In-Memory database like SQLite, and synchronize it on-the-go if something changes in PostgreSQL.

But... it seems a lot development and a bit cumbersome.

Are there more simple and straight-forward solutions?

Comment: What kind of "hurdle" are you talking about? A good database server can sustain many, many requests per second, especially if those are only read requests. How many requests are you expecting that you think Postgres won't be able to handle them?

Comment: It's not only PostgreSQL handling the requests, but also the round-trip time.
It's around 5-10,000 requests per second.

Comment: 10000 requests per second shouldn't be a problem on modern hardware  - of course that depends on the nature of the requests. If those queries are aggregations that deal with hundreds of millions of rows then apparently not. But if those are "simple" lookups that can make use of indexes efficiently I wouldn't expect many problems. Get a server with a lot of CPUs, enough RAM and fast harddisks (preferrably SSDs) and you don't need the additional complexity of synchronizing an in-memory database

Comment: Ok, that at least sounds good. But I'm still concerned about round-trip times.
My Node.JS is running on Amazon server, and the PostgreSQL is via Compose (remotely).

Comment: I can get about 9000 (read/write) transactions/Second (using [pgbench](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html)) on a 6 year old server in our local network running VMWare Postgres on it.

Comment: With round-trip times I'm thinking of the fact that the PostgreSQL is on another hosting enviroment (Compose) than my own. So reads has to go over the internet.

Comment: Are you sure you need so many queries? A more complicated query that returns several rows at once is usually faster.

Comment: It's a query returning a simple row each time. Doing some packet inspection on on each packet on a socket.